# How to create wind effect in spritekit

Tags: sprite-kit

I was playing angry birds and arrived at this stage where the wind "blows" you and kinda pushes you. was kinda interesting but I really couldnt figure the logic or code that would accomplish this.
I know that you could probably use the emitter to create the wind like "look" 
but i would really like some insight on how you would accomplish the "pushing" of the sprite.

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are right about the fact that the emitter can only be used to give the illusion that a wind is blowing.

I am assuming here that you have physicsBodies attached to the nodes which are to be affected by the wind.

In your -update: method,

```
-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime
{

    if (windOn)
    {
        for (SKNode *node in self.children)
        {
            if (node.physicsBody.categoryBitMask == whateverCategory)
            {
                [node.physicsBody applyForce:CGVectorMake(200, 0)];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This simulates a wind blowing from left to right. You will have to adjust the vector to achieve the desired direction and magnitude of the force.

Comment: oh a force, and walking left will show the sprite "struggling" across the wind like>?

Comment: I am sorry, but I dont understand what you mean. The force will affect the node based on how it is currently moving. So, if the node is going against the 'wind', it will slow down; if it is going with the wind, it will speed up, and if it is falling down, it will fall towards the right.

Comment: Thanks, that was what i was asking